# Are there other Dnsmasq type programs that can return client specific tables?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dnsmasq

We are using Dnsmasq, we have several entries that are working well. What we are looking for is to return a different config file for specific ip addresses.

i.e: 
When ever ip `1.2.3.4` connects, it will use this table:

```
address=/widgits.com/2.2.2.2
address=/x.widgits.com/2.2.2.22
```

When ever ip `2.3.4.5` connects, it will use this table:

```
address=/widgits.com/3.3.3.3
address=/x.widgits.com/3.3.3.33
```

Other than modifying dnsmasq, are there any options out there?

Update: Just wanted to add that we have over 10,000 ip addresses (on the asme interface) that would be split into two groups, and we have up to 300 changes a day that need to be done in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a feature in BIND called views.

> The view clause allows BIND to provide different functionality based
>   on the hosts accessing it

Get more information here: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html

More info possibly here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software

Comment: Just wanted to add that we have over 10,000 ip addresses (on the asme interface) that would be split into two groups, and we have up to 300 changes a day that need to be done in real time. Would I have to restart the service every time I added a new view modification? If so, is there any other options?

Comment: rndc reload should be a lightweight way to signal the process that something has changed and needs to be reread.

Comment: are the number of ip's going to be an issue? (upwards or over 10,000)

Comment: I would imagine the time to reload will be function of the number of zones more than the number of IPs total.http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/excerpt/dnsbindcook_ch05/?page=2

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet seems to be the `-y` (or `--localise-queries`) option. From the [documentation](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> Return answers to DNS queries from /etc/hosts which depend on the interface over which the query was received. If a name in /etc/hosts has more than one address associated with it, and at least one of those addresses is on the same subnet as the interface to which the query was sent, then return only the address(es) on that subnet. This allows for a server to have multiple addresses in /etc/hosts corresponding to each of its interfaces, and hosts will get the correct address based on which network they are attached to. Currently this facility is limited to IPv4.

Comment: All the IP's that have to be split are on the same interface and subnet.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't cover your cases, but it can be better than nothing in some scenarios. Maybe I should have phrased my answer differently.